# Error android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos in MockLocationProvider.pushLocation

Tags: android

I simulate `GPS` position in app Android and when I do

```
myMockLocationProvider.pushLocation(37.422, -122.084);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos at mylab.MockLocationProvider.pushLocation(MockLocationProvider.java:36)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and I have just realized that I was using a mobile with an API version of 16. 
When I looked at the documentation of `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()` they say that this method was added only after the API version is 17. So, I guess you are using a device with an API lower than 17.

Try the following code and see if it works:

```
Location loc = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
loc.setLatitude(37.422);
loc.setLongitude(-122.084);
loc.setAltitude(0);
loc.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
loc.setAccuracy(10);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
    loc.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
```

Comment: For me, I was setting `minSdkVersion = 17` but the user could download my app un-officially! His device was rooted as mentioned in `crashlytics`.